# Can't overwrite main level CSS in Ruby on Rails tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a CSS file that controls all form elements with the following code:

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 15px;
@include box_sizing;
}
```

I have one form though that I don't want the width: 100% element so I try setting up an ID for the input specifically as such

```
#analysis {
 .input {
   width: auto;
  }
}
```

In my form which is written in Ruby on Rails I call a radio button as follows

```
<%= radio_button_tag :choice, "best_beer", true, class: "analysis" %>
```

I can inspect the element, it shows that it's using the analysis class, however the first CSS always takes precedents.  I don't know much about CSS but I'm using the logic found here: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/ Where a ID based CSS should take control over an HTML selector, why is it not doing so for me? Is it because my class is in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes in your second SCSS or LESS file (3 if it is only a CSS file).

1. Should be `input` (for `<input/>`), not `.input` (for `<ANY class="input"/>`).
2. `#analysis input` selects **all `<input/>` inside something with the id `analysis`**, not `<input id="analysis"/>`.

This CSS rule should work:

```
input.analysis {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the id and the class for the element and you shouldn't be nesting selectors since they both directly apply to the same element. You're using the `#analysis` selector in your CSS, which is for an element with the id of `analysis`, but in your embedded Ruby you're tagging the element with the `analysis` class. With the Ruby you're using, try this CSS:

```
input.analysis {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick.  And yea I see what you mean by ID and class.  I had tried putting that class in the original statement but I don't think it worked.  Breaking it out and just leaving it how you typed it worked perfect.  Thank you.